# MySQL, ORM Eloquent. Получить среднее значение

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

Использую Eloquent отдельно от Laravel и PHP. Имеется таблица MySQL. Мне необходимо получить среднюю цену товара.

В таблице есть номер товара (не ID), который дублируется и цена товара.

```
product_id | price
630184     | 300
630184     | 320
630184     | 280
```

Секция `price` соответственно цена, а `code` идентификатор товара.

Каким способом я могу узнать среднюю цену с помощью Eloquent / MySQL?

Я могу получить все записи с ID товара и после разделить количество на общую стоимость, из чего могу получить среднюю цену, но записей может быть довольно много (до нескольких млн), что существенно замедляет общее время выполнения запроса.

Структура таблицы:

`code Index varchar(15)` - может быть только строкой.

`price varchar(255)` - зачастую цифра с плавающей точкой.

При выполнении операции: `select avg(price) from product where code like '01%';` я получаю около 300 тысяч записей и вывожу среднее значение по `price` за 10 - 13 секунд, что довольно долго, так как записей может быть на порядок больше.

Comment: Использовать агрегатную фукнцию **AVG()** -> `select avg(price) from table where product_id = 123`

Comment: @SwaD К сожалению по запросу  `select avg(price) from product where code like '%01';` я получаю почти 300 тысяч записей (их может быть и больше), подсчет среднего значения занимает у меня локально от 10 до 13 секунд (что очень долго), на серверном железе будет ещё медленнее.

Comment: Значит у вас более 300к разных product_id, которые заканчиваются на 01

Comment: Что еще за code? Этого в вопросе не было, уточните его.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov  `code` - это номер или группа продукта, в вопросе данный столбец назван `product_id` для более легкого понимания вопроса.

Comment: не надо ходить вокруг да около. Структур таблицы с индексами в студию и почему ищите по like. `code like '%..'` приводит к чтению всей таблицы.

Comment: @teran в полной таблице нет смысла, так как другие данные не нужны в данной задаче. По like ищу так, как это может быть конкретный товар, а может быть и группа (первые цифры у группы товаров одни). Пример: 417 - ювелирные украшения, 4171 - ювелирные украшения с золотом, 41711 - ювелирные украшения с золотом не более 1 карат, 41712 - ювелирные украшения с золотом более 1 карата. P.S - в примере перепутал место знака вопроса, он должен быть в конце, а не начале, индексы есть на code|product_id.

Comment: `code` это число или строка мы гадать должны? план выполнения хоть покажите

Comment: @teran обновил вопрос

Comment: где `explain`, и почему цена это строка? зы: при выполнении `select avg` без группировки, хз как можно получить более одной записи (раз вы говорите 300к), или относительно запроса, вы опять сочли оставшуюся часть ненужной. Или таки получаете одну, но запрос затрагивает 300к?

Comment: В этом случае вам нужно определиться, среднюю цену ЧЕГО вы хотите сосчитать. Это средняя цена групп товаров, или же конкретных (конечных) товаров? Если первое, то в этом случае вам нужно сделать нормализацию product_id на составляющие по правилам, которые вы уже описали, и делать группировку и суммирование уже по ним.